# swappiness is zero but swap is still used unnecessarily

Tags: kubuntu, swap

On my Kubuntu 12.04 system with an SSD, I have swappiness set to zero (as reported by `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`), but occasionally the system will begin to use swap, even though memory usage is only sixty or seventy percent (e.g. right now the RAM usage is 64% and the swap usage is 3%).  Is this normal?  If so, why?  If not, why is it happening?

I have an idea that it could be related to disabling the cache in Firefox (which I do for the same reason I set swappiness to 0, viz. to minimize writes to disk); I think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90337) might be saying that lower-than-default swappiness values will *increase* the kernel's tendency to swap out such stuff.  Is that right?  But even if so, I don't see why any swapping *at all* would happen when swappiness is *zero* and there's still plenty of RAM.

In case the raw numbers matter, this machine has 2 GB of memory and a swap partition of the same size.

Edited to add:  Using both of the methods proposed by Rinzwind below, I have found to my surprise that there are multiple processes using swap, and Firefox is not among them.  The biggest users are KDE components.  Here are all the processes making nonzero use of swap, and the amount of swap they are using (thanks to Rinzwind's first suggestion):

```
kwin 15040 kB
plasma-desktop 11668 kB
ksmserver 4752 kB
kglobalaccel 4136 kB
kded4 3860 kB
kactivitymanage 3684 kB
kwalletd 3436 kB
knotify4 3052 kB
kdeinit4 2768 kB
bluedevil-helpe 2720 kB
kio_file 2492 kB
kio_file 2492 kB
klauncher 2464 kB
kio_thumbnail 2392 kB
Xorg 648 kB
cupsd 516 kB
polkitd 460 kB
udevd 380 kB
udevd 380 kB
udevd 376 kB
upowerd 280 kB
rsyslogd 212 kB
obex-data-serve 176 kB
ksysguardd 176 kB
avahi-daemon 176 kB
dbus-daemon 132 kB
avahi-daemon 92 kB
kwrapper4 84 kB
upstart-udev-br 80 kB
init 60 kB
bluetoothd 48 kB
x-session-manag 24 kB
NetworkManager 20 kB
udisks-daemon 16 kB
getty 16 kB
udisks-daemon 12 kB
kuiserver 8 kB
```

So my hypothesis is refuted, and I am even more perplexed than before.  I emphasize that in this particular instance swap usage suddenly went from zero to three percent (while I was using Google Maps in Firefox, as it happens).  Why would this be the intended behavior?  And if it isn't, why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

swappiness set to zero does not mean the system does NOT use swap. It tells the kernel to not swap processes out of physical memory *for as long as possible*. And it also does not start swapping when RAM is used up totally.

> Is this normal? If so, why? If not, why is it happening?

The only answer to this is probably: default behaviour. The system decided it is the best action to take.

---

You probably first need to identify the process that is responsible. So this will show swap used per process (run as root or it will report only on processes run by your user):

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less
```

---

There is a tool in the repos called [smem](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/smem.8.html) (also run as root):

```
# smem -s swap -t -k -n
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
    1 0        /sbin/init splash                  0   872.0K     2.2M     5.6M 
  285 0        /lib/systemd/systemd-journa        0     2.6M     2.6M     4.6M 
  307 0        /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd         0     2.1M     2.2M     4.4M 
  616 100      /lib/systemd/systemd-timesy        0   404.0K   435.0K     2.7M 
  711 0        /lib/systemd/systemd-logind        0   960.0K   986.0K     3.0M 
  715 104      /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n              0     1.5M     1.5M     3.6M 
  721 0        /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --        0     6.7M     7.3M    17.4M 
  723 0        /sbin/cgmanager -m name=sys        0   364.0K   401.0K     2.6M 
  735 0        /usr/sbin/thermald --no-dae        0     1.2M     1.4M     8.7M 
  736 0        /usr/sbin/anacron -dsq             0   212.0K   238.0K     2.3M 
  741 105      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syst        0     1.9M     2.1M     5.4M 
  767 0        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/u        0     1.0M     1.1M     5.7M 
 ...

 5097 0        su                                 0   480.0K   675.0K     3.5M 
 5098 0        bash                               0   520.0K     1.0M     3.8M 
 5112 0        /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/sm        0    11.8M    11.8M    14.2M 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  134 12                                          0     1.3G     1.5G     3.3G
```

---

If you follow this and find out a specific program being responsible edit into your question. And I also believe it will be firefox. It is a resource hog so changing browsers might be something to consider.

Comment: So this was very helpful; I'll be using `smem` regularly from now on.  It turns out the Firefox hypothesis was wrong (see the new info).  And in any case, it doesn't really answer the essential question as to why this would happen: suddenly 37 processes start using swap. even though there's more than ten times as much RAM available as they apparently need.